# Trying to find all last names starting with a letter

Tags: string, t-sql, ssms

I'm working a project for school in T-SQL.

I have an Advisors table that is fully set up. I'm trying to update the Student table so that each StudentID is associated with an AdvisorID (referencing the Advisors table). The Student table is fully set up, minus the AdvisorID column. Both tables have Name_Full, Name_First, and Name_Last for every Advisor and Student in the respective tables.

I'm trying to find all students that have a Name_Last starting with 'R'. I know for a fact that there is at least one student that qualifies since there is a student with a Name_Last = 'Ramos'.

I tried searching for every student with a Name_Last starting with the letter 'R' using the following code.

```
SELECT Name_Last
    FROM Student
    WHERE Name_Last IN ('R%')
```

This query returns nothing. I've tried using '=' and 'LIKE' instead of 'IN' and those did not work either. I've tried using 'CONTAINS' which also didn't work. I tried:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('R', Name_Last) = 1
```

This did not work either.
Once I get this working, I'd like to be able to copy it into a WHERE clause using BETWEEN, as I want to assign an AdvisorID to students within certain ranges.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Looks like `where Name_Last like 'R%'` should do the trick. An alternative would be `where left(Name_Last, 1) = 'R'`. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows how the `like` operator does not work for you?

Comment: your minimal, reproducible example could look like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/-K4u-z1e). [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74669469/edit) to include all required details.

Comment: Aside: Note that `Name_Last like 'R%'` can be handled by the query optimizer to use an index on `Last_Name` to perform an _index seek_. Other constructs, e.g. `CharIndex( 'R', Name_Last ) = 1`, may benefit from an _index scan_, but not an _index seek_. Additional reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what was wrong.

The code was working perfectly fine. BUT every Name_Last in Student started with a ' '.

So altering the code to:

```
SELECT Name_Last
    FROM Student
    where Name_Last like ' R%'
```

Worked perfectly. Thank you for your suggestions though!

Comment: You might want to either: (1) fix the data by removing the spurious blank or (b) rename the column to reflect reality, e.g. `Name_Last_With_A_Leading_Space_Unless_It_Happens_To_Be_An_Empty_String`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to trim (remove spaces) first, then take the first letter

```
SELECT Name_Last
FROM Student
WHERE LEFT(LTRIM(Name_Last),1) = 'R'
;
```

Answer (score -1):

The missing part in your statement is the name which is the first word of a full name.

Finds a string that starts with ***'R'***

```
SELECT Name_Last
    FROM Student
    WHERE Name_Last IN ('R%')
```

Finds a string that includes ***' R'***

```
SELECT Name_Last
    FROM Student
    WHERE Name_Last LIKE '% R%'
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Not only will `in ('R%')` not behave like `like 'R%'`. That statement is just a plain copy from the question, where it was already described as not working. The question needs names that _start_ with a letter, this does not align with `% R%`.